# View last used programs in start screen

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, display, tiles

Is there a way to view my last used programs in windows' start screen as individual tiles? I didn't find a way to get it done with "Classic Shell" for Windows

Comment: Hi,

Click the start button and now right click on empty space of that, now click properties. Now you got "Start Menu" properties. In that select the check box for the option, "Store and display recently opened programs in the start menu". 

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then they are in the start menu, but not as tiles in the Windows 8.1 tiles view (start screen), or am I doing something wrong?